# Is there any option to retrieve element from Set/HashSet by it's properties and without creating whole object in java?

Tags: java, java-8

Suppose I have :

```
Set<MyObj> set = new HashSet<>();

set.add(new MyObj("myParam1","myParam2","myParam3"));
set.add(new MyObj("myParam11","myParam22","myParam33"));
set.add(new MyObj("myParam111","myParam222","myParam333"));.....

public class MyObj {
   private String p1;
   private String p2;
   private String p3;

   @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        MyObj myObj = (MyObj) o;
        return Objects.equals(getP1(), myObj.getP1()) &&
                Objects.equals(getP2(), myObj.getP2());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getP1(), getP2());
    }

}
```

I want without creating new Object , retrieve Element by `p1 & p2`

example: I'm getting 2 strings: `"myParam1","myParam2"`

and I want to have result: `MyObj("myParam1","myParam2","myParam3")`

I don't want this:

```
set.stream().filter(a->a.equals(new MyObj("myParam1","myParam2",null))).findFirst()
```

instead i want something like a map (run-time O(1)), without using it.

Answer (score 3):

```
set.stream()
   .filter(x -> x.getMyParam1().equals("myParam1") && x.getMyParam2().equals("myParam2"))
   .findFirst();
```

But think about `findFirst` here for a moment... you are using a `Set`, so it makes little sense. To make this a bit clearer:

```
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
    set.add("hello");
    set.add("world");
    set.add("jug");

    System.out.println(set.stream().findFirst().get()); // world

    // add them
    IntStream.range(0, 100_000)
            .mapToObj(i -> "" + i)
            .forEachOrdered(set::add);

    // remove them immediatly after

    IntStream.range(0, 100_000)
            .mapToObj(i -> "" + i)
            .forEachOrdered(set::remove);

    System.out.println(set.stream().findFirst().get()); // hello
```

Comment: you were faster than me :-)

Comment: sorry , edit my question , i want to retrieve without going over all set...perfectly 0(1) , something like map , without of using it

Comment: @VitalyT You can't do it in O(1) without having a map & without iterating on set

Comment: @VitalyT well, either do by index or by computing a `hash`, you can't do it otherwise

Comment: @VitalyT btw, you don't want to construct that object because it is expensive to compute?

Comment: no , due to the garbage...I have a billion of such objects...how can u compute using hash ?

Comment: @VitalyT you might be prematurely optimizing this - these objects should be cheap to create and clean... what I meant by `hash` was using `hashCode` - you can't do it otherwise

Comment: @VitalyT pre-optimization. The JVM is extremely effective at managing short-lived objects. Use a HashMap<Key, MyObject>, where Key contains p1 and p2 and has proper hashCode() and equals(). Don't worry about the performance of the JVM.

Comment: Is there any way to compute hash by 2 properties and retrieve from set this hash ? cause it stores like a map hashes like this ...why it cannot be 0(1)

Comment: There is a way. That's called a HashMap.

Comment: haha...it is legacy code , i cannot change it , only retrieve

Comment: @JBNizet was going to post this comment... :)

Comment: @VitalyT of course you can. get that `Set<YourObject>` put it into a `Map<YourKey, YourObject>` where `YourKey` consists of `param1` and `param2` and simply search

Comment: i know all this , but it uses additionally memory and i don't have it. Just thought that is it any option maybe in java8 that can retrieve object from set by hash with the efficient optimisations...

Comment: @VitalyT If memory is a problem I suggest not using the Stream API at all! It has a lot of overhead, just use an old for-loop which is pretty much as optimized as it can get

Comment: @VitalyT but if you don't want to pre-otimize use whatever you already have in place and measure to see if you have a problem *at all*.

Comment: @VitalyT you cannot without indexing. Indexing, if you don't want to write your own code, means putting things in a correctly keyed map. You have been given the answer about 5 times and refuse to accept it. A set is not indexed, it is unique - no amount of Java 8 will make it indexed. Without copying it into a correctly keyed map that is...

Answer (score 0):

So why not just do sth. like this inside the filter:

```
a-> "myParam1".equals(a.getP1()) && "myParam2".equals(a.getP2())
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way but below code can filter out the elements matching param string

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;


class MyObj {
private String p1;
private String p2;
private String p3;

public MyObj(String p1, String p2, String p3) {
    super();
    this.p1 = p1;
    this.p2 = p2;
    this.p3 = p3;
}

public String getP1() {
    return p1;
}

public void setP1(String p1) {
    this.p1 = p1;
}

public String getP2() {
    return p2;
}

public void setP2(String p2) {
    this.p2 = p2;
}

public String getP3() {
    return p3;
}

public void setP3(String p3) {
    this.p3 = p3;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o)
        return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
        return false;
    MyObj myObj = (MyObj) o;
    return Objects.equals(getP1(), myObj.getP1()) && Objects.equals(getP2(), myObj.getP2());
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(getP1(), getP2());
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "MyObj [p1=" + p1 + ", p2=" + p2 + "]";
}

}


public class chkfromhashSet {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Set<MyObj> setofmyobjs = new HashSet<>();

    setofmyobjs.add(new MyObj("myParam11", "myParam22", "myParam33"));
    setofmyobjs.add(new MyObj("myParam111", "myParam222", "myParam333"));
    setofmyobjs.add(new MyObj("myParam1", "myParam2", "myParam3"));

    System.out.println(setofmyobjs);

    String s1 = "myParam1";
    String s2 = "myParam2";

    Set<MyObj> setofmyobjsfiltered = setofmyobjs.stream()
            .filter(x -> s1.equalsIgnoreCase(x.getP1()) && s2.equalsIgnoreCase(x.getP2()))
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());

    System.out.println(setofmyobjsfiltered);

}

}
```